# Feathered edge Ellipse p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im looking to create an ellipse with a feathered or soft edge, as if it has been drawn with a spray can. I cant get my head around it...?? :-i
Any Help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to break this down further. Pretend you have a friend who has never seen anything drawn with a spray can, so they have no idea what that looks like. Your goal is to give your friend a piece of paper, a pencil, and a list of steps they can follow to create the effect even though they've never seen it before.

Write down a series of steps (in English, not in code) that your friend could follow using the pen and paper. Remember that your friend has never seen the effect before, so you have to be as specific as possible. Try to break steps down into smaller sub-steps whenever possible. Maybe try watching videos of the effect in slow motion to figure out exactly what's going on.

When you have the list of steps written down, that's an algorithm that you can think about implementing with code.

Even though this doesn't feel like programming, this process of breaking your main goal down into several smaller steps is at the core of programming (especially creative coding).

That being said, I can help you get started by offering several approaches you might want to play with.

- Just use an image stamp. Draw the effect beforehand and then just draw that image to the canvas, optionally randomly rotating and coloring it.
- Or draw a series of circles, maybe getting more transparent as they get further from the center.
- Or draw a random dot within a random range at a random angle. Do this several times per frame.

Comment: Thanks Kevin Workman, you make some really valid points. I did think of the image stamp option but i find that an easy way out and im trying to be a better creative coder so i will use that as a last resort. I like your suggestion of breaking the step right down step by step. I think i need to draw a simple point in the centre and then add recurring points around that first point spacing them further apart as the reach the maximum radius... ok, i need to work onn this some more. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethHorton No problem. If you get stuck, feel free to post a [mcve] in a new question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.